# Changing words in a string to capitalize a text file

Tags: python

In order to fix a bunch all-uppercase text files, I have written a script that:

1. Lowers all characters and capitalizes the first word of each line and the first word after a period.
2. Capitalizes all words that are in a list of city and country names (from another text file)

```py
def lowit(line):
    line = line.lower()
    sentences = line.split('. ')
    sentences2 = [sentence[0].capitalize() + sentence[1:] for sentence in sentences]
    string2 = '. '.join(sentences2)
    return string2

def capcico(line, allKeywords):
    allWords = line.split(' ')
    original = line.split(' ')

    for i,words in enumerate(allWords):
        words = words.replace(',', '')
        words = words.replace('.', '')
        words = words.replace(';', '')

        if words in allKeywords:
            original[i] = original[i].capitalize()

    return ' '.join(original)

def main():
    dfile = open('fixed.txt', 'w') 
    f = open('allist.txt', 'r')
    allKeywords = f.read().split('\n')

    with open('ulm.txt', 'r') as fileinput:
        for line in fileinput:
            low_line = lowit(line)
            dfile.write('\n' + capcico(low_line, allKeywords))
    dfile.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

It works, but the problem is that it doesn't capitalize a city/Country if there are more than one in the same line:

> TOWN IN WUERTTEMBERG, GERMANY.

changes to:

> Town in Wuerttemberg, germany.

Any Ideas to what's wrong?
TNX

Comment: This appears to be doing more than changing the case of letters.

Comment: Why do you switch the position of the city and county? (Though wuerttemberg is a territory / state, not a city)

Comment: Why do you import `chain` and `string` but never use them?

Comment: Right, I'll fix that. Also fixed the position, it was a typing error... Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because "germany" is really "germany\n".
Strip the EOL off the word...

```
words = words.replace(',', '')
words = words.replace('.', '')
words = words.replace(';', '')

# Add in this line to strip the EOL
words = words.rstrip('\r\n')
```

Comment: It salved the problem, Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
#Input
fileinput = open("ulm.txt").read()
##Input lower
filow = fileinput.lower()

#Keywords
allKeywords = open("allist.txt").read().split("\n")
for kw in allKeywords:
    filow = filow.replace(kw.strip().lower(), kw.capitalize())

#Dots
fidots = filow.split(".")
for i,d in enumerate(fidots):
    c = d.strip().capitalize()
    dc = d.replace(c.lower(), c)
    fidots[i] = dc

#Result
dfile = open("fixed.txt", "w")
result = ".".join(fidots)
dfile.write(result)
dfile.close()
```

Comment: I know you should be able to just read the code, but it would be helpful if you explained what you did. Not a criticism, it'd just aid understanding.

Comment: Thanks but [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40491373/7132243) did the job. Your suggestion kept the first word of a paragraph in lower case...